How to manipulate release version while creating a new package version?
We are creating a new package version. Package details is as follows. Note that "Release version" is "61.0"
Name                           Value              
 ────────────────────────────── ────────────────── 
 Name                           v3.4.0             
 Subscriber Package Version Id  04tXXxXXXxXX 
 Package Id                     0HoXXXXXXXXX 
 Version                        3.4.0.6            
 Description                                       
 Branch                         local              
 Tag                                               
 Released                       false              
 Validation Skipped             false              
 Ancestor                       04tXXXXXXXXX 
 Ancestor Version               3.2.0.1            
 Code Coverage                  82.00%             
 Code Coverage Met              true               
 Org-Dependent Unlocked Package N/A                
 Release Version                61.0               
 Build Duration in Seconds      578.0              
 Managed Metadata Removed       Yes                
 Created By                     005XXXXXXXXXX  <==

What do I have to do to create a new package version with "Release Version" set at "60.0"?

Modify the sfdx-project.json file to set the releaseVersion to 60.0.
Also, Refer to this: Target a Specific Release for Your Unlocked Packages During Salesforce Release Transitions and Release a Second-Generation Managed Package

@TusharJadav editing the sfdx-project.json file did not work
